# How come I can't register for a mojang PE account?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm playing minecraft PE 0.7.1 and found out the realms thing was in the update. I went in to register for an account but each time I click "register" it does nothing. Why can't I register?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot or something to work with? It's pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Mojang accounts are only for Mojang PC games, such as Minecraft, Scrolls, etc. you need to buy the pocket edition version.

Comment: @jeffreylin That's apparently no longer true. PE uses Mojang accounts for the new Minecraft Realms functionality. I just used my Mojang account to activate Realms on my PE app.

Comment: @DarkStevie When does it do nothing? Is it when you push the "login/signup" button at top-right of the Realms screen, when you click the "Register" link above the login form, or when you push the big "Register" button under the register form after putting in your info? Also: do you have PE full or lite?

Comment: Have the full version and its the BIG register button. Also how do I add screenshots on here if I'm using this on my iPod

Answer (score 1):

By all reports there is a bug in 0.7.1 that interferes with registration through the Minecraft PE app. Existing Mojang accounts can be used to login, but trying to register a new one doesn't work.

There is a workaround: register a Mojang account using a browser directly at [Mojang's account registration site](https://account.mojang.com/register), then use that to login. I already had a Mojang account and managed to use it to login to Realms just fine.